# Making html menubar

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

Hey I am trying to make a topbar for my site as a navigation bar. This is what I get currently, how can I make it so that it's connected to the sides and to top. I don't want that space between the page and the bar. Sorry I am very beginner in this. See this picture to see what my page looks like now http://i55.tinypic.com/dgnpro.png

My CSS code for bar

```
#topbar
{
    background-image:url(../images/topbar.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;

}
```

Comment: If we could see some of the HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript, it would help.

Comment: Can you show some HTML/CSS? Showing us a graphic is not helpful; it's like showing a snapshot of someone's chest when one is trying to diagnose lung cancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add on your css `html, body {margin:0; padding:0;}` This will make your bar to start of your page from the start without any space.